# Query attribute within an object

Tags: typescript

I need the ID within an object. When I try the following, I get the Typescript error/notice below.

```
type SINGLEUSER = {
 id:string,
 name:string,
 email:string,
 image:string,
 emailVerified: any
}

let singleUser:SINGLEUSER =  JSON.stringify(user)


const user_ = await db
 .collection("accounts")
 .findOne({_id: singleUser.id })
```

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'SINGLEUSER'.ts(2322)

The data arrives like this:

> ```
>      {"id":"645e2c7e31041f8404b8a260","name":"Max Mustermann","email":"m.mustermann@gmx.de","image":"https://...","emailVerified":null}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

When doing `JSON.stringify(user)`, you actually convert the user JSON object to a string, and then its not compatible with the type `SINGLEUSER`.
Remove the usage of it like so:

```
let singleUser:SINGLEUSER =  user
```

if the `user` object is compatible with the type, you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

- `JSON.stringify` returns a string from a JSON object
- `JSON.parse` returns an object from a string.

In your case, `singleUser` is an object with the type `SINGLEUSER`.

So if `user` is a string, you should use `JSON.parse` instead if it's already an object, you should just assign: `singleUser = user`